# UINavigationController's interactivePopGestureRecognizer not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to implement a custom `id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>` object when pushing one particular view controller on to the navigation controller's navigation stack.

However, I have discovered, that doing so prevents the UINavigation controller for using the default interactive transition, **even on view controllers that do not use my custom transition**.

I have no idea why this is occurring.

After further investigation, I have found that returning nil from the method

```
- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                               animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
                                            fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                              toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
```

somehow disables the default interactive transition as well.

How can I continue using the UINavigationController's default interactive transition in some instances, while also using a custom Transition object in others?

Comment: What is the question you want to ask?

Comment: I am experiencing this exact problem. Wish there were a better solution than the one posted.

Comment: I ended up setting the delegate to nil when i didn't want the custom transition.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [blog post](http://blommegard.se/blog/2014/01/31/a-take-on-custom-transitions-with-uinavigationcontroller/) detailing a possible solution. I have not tested it. Seems quite a hackish workaround. As the author says it will probably break if Apple changes things, but hey.

Quote:

> What I ended up doing was creating a new instance of a
>   `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`, configure it with the left edge and
>   set the exact same target/action as our
>   `interactivePopGestureRecognizer`, with other words, the instance of
>   `_UINavigationInteractiveTransition` and the action `handleNavigationTransition:`. And finally add it to the
>   `UINavigationControllers` view. There is a bit of `-valueForKey:` and
>   `NSSelectorFromString()` in the final solution that I am not very proud
>   of, but it works perfectly. Remember to be safe when implementing a
>   solution like this, Apple change stuffs, as we all know.